# UITableViewCell disappear while scrolling fast

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I know there are tons of questions about tableViewCell disappearing on scroll, but none of those fit into my situation.

I say disappear, I mean the whole cell disappears, not some of its subviews.

Here's my situation: 
I have a tableView with custom cells, each one of them is very complex, some could even host up to three collectionViews in them. Most of these cells are only displayed once, so I cache them. I retrieve data from network, and use it to populate the cells. As sometimes the data may not be fully available, some sections of the cell needs to be hidden: the cell will set some of its collectionViews' height constraint to zero, and isHidden to true, then notify the tableView, who will reload the cells' heights using:

```
    tableView.beginUpdate()
    tableView.endUpdate()
```

I have noticed two behaviors:

## 1:

If none of the cell's portion is hidden, the cell works perfectly, except when I scroll(from bottom up) too fast, the cell disappears before going out of the bound of the tableView. When I scroll slow, this does not happen.

## 2:

If some part of the cell is hidden, the cell will disappear before going out of tableView EVEN WHEN I scroll very slowly.

Sorry I cannot post any code, but what I might have done wrong?

P.S.: In my tableView's row height delegate method, I have:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return cellHeights[indexPath.row] ?? 0.1
}
```

`cellHeights` is where I use a dictionary to store computed height of the corresponding cell. I am certain that these height values are correct, because when I scroll from top down, the cell looks all right. This only happens when I scroll from bottom up.

I did some experiment with the default height `0.1`. When I changed it to `1000`, the cells are disappearing randomly even more. `0.1` looks relatively stable, but the problems above still exist.

Thanks.

Comment: can I see cellForRowAtIndexPath of tableview

Comment: Try implementing estimatedHeightForRowAt  UITableViewDelegate method and return the same height that you have returned in heightForRowAt  UITableViewDelegate method.

Comment: It gives me this error (crash on startup) after I have implemented estimatedRowHeight: *** Assertion failure in -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.7.47/UITableViewRowData.m:537
libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception @PGDev