# Convert Complex UITableView to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uistoryboard

I currently have a prototyped UITableView in my storyboard, which has many cell with very complex layout. Now, I need to convert it into a UICollectionView, because I always have some problem with the way UITableView handles cell layout(See my [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627711/uitableviewcell-disappear-while-scrolling-fast)). I figured the code part to be the easy one, as I only need to tweak the inheritance of my cell classes, as well as switch the delegate and datasource with previously written code. However, I am a little stuck on the storyboard side, that is, given all my cells are complex in layout and even copying and pasting them from one cell to another would require many layout tweaking and IBOutlet/IBAction reconnecting. Is there a fast way to convert those UITableViewCells designed in storyboard into UICollectionViewCells?

Comment: Use storyboard source code to do that. Copy the relevant code of UITableViewCell and paste it to UICollectionViewCell. This is a bit complex task. I suggest you create a new UICollectionViewCell instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you save data into one class, In CollectionView, You get data from class. You remember, tableview and collection are  reverse about cell and row.